# Change Name of Html.DropDownListFor - MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a form with a drop down for a property named "Event". Unfortunately this is a reserved word so it won't work as usual:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Event, new SelectList(ViewData["Events"] as IEnumerable<JFS.Data.Model.Event>, "Id", "Name"))
```

In the controller I can't take this value separately as it is a reserved word, so if I do this:

```
public ActionResult Create(int event)
{
etc etc
}
```

It throws an error.

What I would ideally like to do is change the name of the dropdown list, something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Event as eventId, new SelectList(ViewData["Events"] as IEnumerable<JFS.Data.Model.Event>, "Id", "Name"))
```

But that doesn't work. Anyone know of the correct way to change the name? :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the name generated by HTML helpers and this is by design. What you could do instead is to change the name of your action parameter and prefix it with `@` which allows to use reserved words in C# as variable names:

```
public ActionResult Create(int @event)
{
    etc etc
}
```

But in general it is not recommended to use reserved words as variable names unless absolutely necessary. And in your case it is not absolutely necessary because there's a much better solution which of course consists in using a view model:

```
public class CreateEventViewModel
{
    public int Event { get; set; }
}
```

and then having your controller action take this view model as argument:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateEventViewModel model)
{
    etc etc
}
```

Comment: Why should it be prefixed?

Comment: Perfect - lifesaver! Thank you very much

Comment: Ohhhh you see Darin you need a little directions :D

Comment: @IamStalker, it should be prefixed because [`event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea.aspx) is a reserved word in C#. If you want to use reserved words (such as `if`, `event`, `class`, `foreach`, ...) as variable names you could prefix them with `@`. But as I've already pointed out in my answer this is not recommended and shouldn't be used unless you have absolutely no other way around which has never happened to me personally.

Comment: Thanks Darin. If I were to use a prefix in this case (as it is a rare instance) what problems would potentially arise?

Comment: Nevermind, I've done it the right way ;) Thanks for your help

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you see Darin, I've already knew it, i just asked you why you suggested it without explain, but nice answer.

Comment: Why I suggested what? To use a view model? Come on, I though that was obvious :-) You should always use view models in an ASP.NET MVC application. That's the answer to 99.9999999% of the questions on StackOverflow about ASP.NET MVC, including this one :-)